# Creating an npm package with contracts from api so that front app can use it (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nestjs

I am unsure if this concept exists in Typescript, and am seeking guidance on how to accomplish it.

I have a frontend app and a dedicated backend REST API with defined contract classes for Inputs and Outputs. These classes specify the allowed inputs for requests and the expected outputs for users.

Is it possible to create a package by importing these classes so that the frontend app can use them to generate proper request data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not :)
Go ahead and add your contracts in a package that you then import and utilize. An option is to use **Github packages**.

Basically, you create your package as a regular repo and then publish it as a package (can be private package as well) on Github.

The trick to make this happen is to put an .npmrc file in the root folder of the project that is importing the package. In it you would write something like this:

```
@your-github-organization-name:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Comment: thanks, I will try that, didn't know about github packages :)

Comment: good luck! it really makes things easier

Comment: I manage to do it thanks to your advise, thanks :)